# PHP: MoveUploadedFile -> name.jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg() ... is not a valid JPEG file in 

Tags: php

I do have a problem: On my website, I allow user to upload an image in every format. Then, on the server I run MoveUploadedFile() and as param I give it a name with '.jpg' in the end. It gets saved and on Windows, I can properly open the image. But if I want to open it with 'imagecreatefromjpeg()' then the function returns "image.jpg is not a valid JPEG file in ...."

What do I have to do so this does not happen anymore?

Thanks for answers ;)

Regz, Flo

Comment: Are you using the correct path? Do a `is_file()` on the path you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write Porsche on a Fiat which dont change the fact its still a Fiat.

the user can upload a file in every format but imagecratefromjpeg expects a jpg. 
windows just use the same program to open the picture, no mater if jpg or gif or whatever. (or what name it has)